# Соблюдается ли безопасность при записи в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Я при записи в базу текста из формы, я убрав регулярное выражение, которое не допускает к записи в базу запрещенные символы. Но вместо этого я использую функцию:

```
function filter($msg) {
    $msg = trim($msg);
    $msg = htmlspecialchars($msg);
    $msg = mysql_escape_string($msg);

    return $msg;
}
```

и текст записываю в базу запросом:

```
$post = filter($_POST['msg'];
mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `nick` = '$post' WHERE `id` = '$us[id]' LIMIT 1");
```

при таком записи в базу, безопасно ли? или же нужно использовать регулярное выражение. Мне просто нужно чтобы все символы записывались.

Comment: Желательно использовать PDO

Answer (score 4):

Нет, это небезопасно.

Но ещё более небезопасно использовать решение из соседнего ответа.

Что надо делать.

- Функцию filter() выкинуть
- функцию mysql_query() выкинуть
- взять PDO, переписать свой запрос так:

  ```
  $sql = "UPDATE user SET nick = ? WHERE id = ?";
  $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$_POST['msg'], $us['id']]);
  ```

Comment: Ну ладно вам гнобить чужие ответы. Давайте правильные ответы, вот и будет безопасно задавать вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде есть несколько проблем.

1. Расширение `mysql` устарело. Лучше использовать `mysqli` или `PDO`.
2. Функция `mysql_escape_string` давным-давно устарела и не учитывает кодировку БД. Используйте вместо нее `mysql_real_escape_string`.
3. Использовать `htmlspecialchars` было бы правильнее при *выводе* строки на странице (хотя это и субъективно).
4. Что-то мне подсказывает, что вот это `'$us[id]'` тоже неплохо было бы обезопасить.
5. Использование `htmlspecialchars` и `trim` изменяют исходные данные (см. UPD2).

Таким образом, ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
function filter($msg) {
    $msg = trim($msg);
    $msg = htmlspecialchars($msg); // Надо использовать при выводе, а не здесь
    $msg = mysql_real_escape_string($msg);

    return $msg;
}

mysql_query(sprintf(
    "UPDATE `user` SET `nick` = '%s' WHERE `id` = '%d' LIMIT 1",
    filter($_POST['msg']),
    intval($us['id']) // Теперь id точно число.
));
```

**UPD1:**

В случае, если в проекте есть возможность вообще отказаться от расширения `mysql`, лучше бы перейти на использование `PDO` (как советует @Ипатьев).

**UPD2:**

Дополнительно скажу еще и про правильность кода (с точки зрения логики, а не безопасности). Использование `htmlspecialchars` и `trim` *изменяют* исходные данные. Более того `htmlspecialchars` не должна применяться к данным при записи, а должна использоваться при их выводе на страницу (для предотвращения XSS). Таким образом, если все что требуется, это безопасно поместить данные в базу с использованием расширения `msyql` достаточно выполнить следующий код:

```
mysql_query(sprintf(
    "UPDATE `user` SET `nick` = '%s' WHERE `id` = '%d' LIMIT 1",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']),
    intval($us['id'])
));
```

Если нет ограничений на выбор расширения для работы с MySQL, лучше использовать `PDO` (см. UPD1).

Comment: Там где вы написали "// Лучше использовать при выводе" надо писать "// Надо использовать при выводе". Тут этой функции делать не чего.

Comment: В целом согласен. Но тут многое завит от того, есть ли экранирование при выводе содержимого на страницу. Если нет -- то будет XSS. Хотя пример обновил =)

Comment: @Денис хочешь полной безопасности? - используй хранимые процедуры

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я бы вообще исключил mysqli как вариант, оставил только PDO (из-за плейсхолдеров и унифицированного интерфейса).

Comment: @Etki, в целом да. Для новых проектов `PDO` -- это лучшее решение. Но если говорить о каком-то legacy коде, то перейти с `mysql` на `mysqli` мне кажется несколько проще благодаря схожим интерфейсам.

Comment: Использовать `htmlspecialchars` — ужасно. А если в базу попадает хэш от пароля, вы тоже будете заменять символы, да?

Comment: @VladD, причем тут хеш пароля? Речь в исходном вопросе была о _безопасности_ конкретного куска кода. Использование `htmlspecialchars` здесь неправильно, но безопасно с точки зрения SQL инъекций.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: `htmlspecialchars` защищает от SQL-инъекций? о_О

Comment: @VladD нет, но и новых не добавляет. =) Кстати как и `trim`, на который вы внимания не обратили.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Ну, я и на `mysql_real_escape_string` внимания не обратил. Но раз `htmlspecialchars` не защищает от инъекций, и только искажает записываемую в базу информацию, то зачем оно нужно? Например, в случае, если `nick` таки означает ник, эта строчка просто так не даёт использовать в нике двойные кавычки или так знак `&`.

Comment: @VladD Вообще безопасности и корректность кода это несколько разные вещи. Безопасный кода не всегда бывает корректным. Как бы то ни было, я добавил UPD2 про использование `trim` и `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: У меня никогда не было случаев, чтобы безопасность влияла на корректность. Если программа некорректна, это уже финиш. Кроме того, в конкретно вашем случае некорректность вовсе не нужна.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: С UPD2 согласен, по модулю того, что я не вполне уверен в `mysql_real_escape_string`. Но я не уверен, что можно обойтись без PDO.

Comment: @VladD, если речь идет о расширении `mysql`, то `mysql_real_escape_string` делает свое дело. Хотя в идеале нужно переходить на `PDO`.